# How to make the response more dynamic?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say in `PostgreSQL` database I have table called `relationship`. That table contains a list of factors for a particular survey which user selected. There are certain questions to each of these factors.

`relationship` table looks like this:

```
| SURVEY_ID                            | FACTOR_ID | QUESTION_IDS |
|--------------------------------------|-----------|--------------|
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | 1         | {1,2,3,4}    |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | 2         | {5,6}        |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | 3         | {7,8,9}      |
```

In the second table which called `answers` I store information about the results of users' answers to each of the questions? Below you can notice just little example of the data in the second table:

```
| SURVEY_ID                            | EMPLOYEE | QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT                                             | OPTION_ID | OPTION_TEXT       |
|--------------------------------------|----------|-------------|-----------------------------------------------------------|-----------|-------------------|
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | AMELIA   | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 1         | Strongly disagree |      |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | SOPHIE   | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 2         | Disagree          |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | ISABELLA | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 3         | Rather disagree   |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | MIA      | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 4         | Rather disagree   |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | JESSICA  | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 5         | Rather disagree   |
| 7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e | RUBY     | 1           | Our organization inspires me to do the best work          | 6         | Rather disagree   |
```

You can notice sql query below where all questions and factors are accurately recorded. How can I make the response to this request dynamic?

For example if user select not all 3 factor in survey. He just select several factors. Let's say one or two from `relationship` table. I want to calculate only that selected factors. Right now I calculate all 3 factor and return the result. Is there any way to make it dynamic?

I will be glad to any help and advice.

```
SELECT
    (
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 1 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 2 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 3 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 4 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
    ) / 4 * 100 AS FIRST_FACTOR,
    (
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 5 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 6 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
    ) / 2 * 100 AS SECOND_FACTOR,
    (
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 7 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 8 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        +
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 9 AND ANSWERS.OPTION_ID IN(5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
        /
        NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN ANSWERS.QUESTION_ID = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::FLOAT, 0)
    ) / 3 * 100 THIRD_FACTOR
FROM
    ANSWERS
WHERE
    ANSWERS.SURVEY_ID = '7eefcc5e-75ed-4836-b7f6-8206484f081e'
```

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times but I couldn't really work out what you're asking.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: I think your problem is with how to store question_ids in the relationship table. Why is it an array? if there is a one-to-many relationship then store a row for each question. This will make crafting queries much simpler.

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry for my poor English. Let me try you to explain it more details. For example I have id of a specific survey. That survey has several factors which selected by some user. In `relationship` table you can see relationship between surveys and factors. Let's say user select only first factor, not all three. In that case I need to make calculations with 4 question as in my example. The result in this case is a single number. The problem is that it is not known in advance how many factors will be selected by the user? I hope you understand me.

Comment: @TheImpaler my code presented in the post works only if the user has chosen all 3 factors from `relationship` table. It return 3 number. Let's say user select only first factor, not all three. In that case I need to make calculations with 4 question as in my example. The result in this case is a single number. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @maxTrialfire I have a separate table where the relationship between factors and questions is stored as you adviced, but how it could solve my problem?

Comment: Why don't you just join the questions table in and add `and factor_id in (1,2)` to the end of the query if the user chooses only factors 1 and 2. The representation of the question ids is a bit of a nuisance at the moment; these should be expanded to each have their own row and repeat the factor id

Comment: @CaiusJard sounds good, but could you please give an example code based on what you said earlier.